# How to overwrite the existing classes of Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I use the Shadcn library, but when I use `dir="rtl"` , the whole component is not placed correctly in the Rtl mode because styles like pl ml, .... are given in it (Because this library still cannot properly support Rtl).

I want to rewrite Tailwind classes. Now how can I convert `mr-*` classes to `me-*`?

I used the following code on Tailwind config, But this code does not work because it can only create a new class and not rewrite a class.

```
plugins: [

    plugin(function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {

      matchUtilities(

        {

          mr: (value) => ({

            marginInlineEnd: value,

          }),

        },

        { values: theme("marginInlineEnd") }

      );

    }),

  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

As of [version `3.3.0`](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v3.3.0), Tailwind supports logical CSS properties in the inline direction (such as `margin-inline-end`) as per [pull request #10166](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/10166).

---

However, to answer your question directly, you can [disable the core plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#core-plugins) for `margin` to provide your own

```js
corePlugins: {
  margin: false,
},
```

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      marginInlineEnd: ({ theme }) => theme('margin'),
    },
  },
  corePlugins: {
    margin: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          mr: (value) => ({
            marginInlineEnd: value,
          }),
        },
        { values: theme("marginInlineEnd") }
      );
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="mr-10">Foo</div>Bar
</div>
```

Though please be aware that this would also disable all the other `margin` classes like `m-*`, `my-*`, etc. so you'd have to redeclare them if you were planning on using them.